# Checking if reversed array is the same as original one

Tags: c++

I have a homework task to check if reversed array would be the same as the original one using functions. I have tried to write the code but it gives me the same "TAIP" answer everytime I run it. I read a tutorial how to reverse an array, so I have tried to have 2 arrays: original one and reversed one and then I compare it. However, it doesn't work in my code and I don't know why.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
void funk(int a[], int n, int b[], int &nes);

int main()
{
    int a[10], n, b[10],nes = 0;

    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> a[i];
        b[i] = a[i];//the same elements
    }

    funk(a, n, b, nes);
    if (nes != 0) {
        cout << "NE";
    }
    else
        cout << "TAIP";

}

void funk(int a[], int n, int b[], int &nes) {
    int j, i=0, pap;
    j = i - 1; //last element

    while (i < j)
    {
        pap = b[i];
        b[i] = b[j];
        b[j] = pap;
        i++;
        j--;
    }
    for (int c = 0; c < n; c++) {
        if (a[c] != b[c]) {
      nes++;
      break;
        }
    }
}
```

Input:

```
6
8 5 8 1 3 8
```

Output I need to get: `NE`

Comment: If you want `nes` to act as an output, (i.e. running the function changes the value outside of the function), you will have to pass it by reference: (`int& nes`) instead of by value (`int nes`).

Comment: Oh, I've missed that. However this doesn't fix the problem with the code.

Comment: Free tip: this can be determined using a single array only. Two arrays are not needed, at all. Do you know how pointers work? Start one at the beginning of the array, a second one at the end of the array. Keep incrementing the first one, decrementing the other one, while checking if they're pointing to the same value. When they reach the other end of the array, you're done. Wasn't that easy?

Comment: Simply check that `a[i]` is equal to `a[n-i-1]` for all `i` (from `0` to `n/2`).

Comment: It's surprising how C++ teachers keep bothering students so much with C-style arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach seems to be unnecessarily complicated and inefficient. For a *reverse-invariant* array `a` of `n` elements, the condition `a[i]==a[n-i-1]` must be `true` for all `i` between `0` and `n/2`.

An exemplary solution:

```
template <typename T>
bool is_reverse_invariant(T a[], size_t n)
{
   for (size_t i = 0; i < n/2; i++)
      if (a[i] != a[n-i-1]) return false;
   return true;
}
```

---

A problem with your code

```
int j, i=0, pap;
j = i - 1; //last element
```

is that `j` should be initialized with

```
j = n - 1;
```

instead.

Comment: Maybe you could add if (n == 0) return true;

Comment: @MFnx I changed `i <= n/2` to `i < n/2`, which avoids unnecessary additional check.